# Android 2.1 - Video issue

Tags: android, video

Why does my video playing app crash when I try to run on a Droid 2.1 device, but works fine with myTouch 1.6?

Thanks
Chris

LogCat shows

```
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252): java.lang.IllegalStateException
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.media.MediaPlayer.getVideoWidth(Native Method)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.widget.VideoView$2.onPrepared(VideoView.java:290)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.media.MediaPlayer$EventHandler.handleMessage(MediaPlayer.java:1152)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4363)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:860)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:618)
06-07 18:13:13.444: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(4252):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: I am assuming you have the android SDK installed and know your way around it. Can you please show the stack trace that your Droid throws when it crashes.

Answer (score 0):

[This `VideoView`-based sample](http://github.com/commonsguy/cw-advandroid/tree/master/Media/Video/) works fine on all Android devices I have tested it upon, including the Magic and DROID. Experiment with it and your media clip and see what happens.